# Ajax call not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to clear some session variables after a successful call to Realex ( company that processes the credit card transaction ). The session variables contain my shopping cart contents, so once the transaction is successful, I want to clear it out. My code is as follows:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    async: false,                                       
                    url: templateuri+'/realex_go_pay.php',                  
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {                                                         
                        amount: ordertotal,
                        orderid: orderid,
                        orderkey: orderkey,
                        cardtype: type,
                        cardnumber: number,
                        cardname: name,
                        expdate: expiry,
                        cvv: cvv,
                        issueno: issueno
                    },
                    success: function(data){                        
                        // Hide payment indicator.
                        jQuery('.realex_payindicator').hide();
                        data = data.split("|");
                        if (data[0] == '00'){                                                                                                                                           
                            // Empty the shopping cart.
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                async: false,                                                                       
                                url: templateuri+'/realex_empty_cart.php'                                                               
                            });
                            self.location = thankyoupage+'?order='+orderid+'&key='+orderkey;                                                                                            
                        }else{
                            alert(data);                            
                        }                       
                    }
                });
```

The first call to realex_go_pay.php is working no problem. But the second call to realex_empty_cart.php does not seem to be working. In realex_empty_cart.php, I only have two lines of code:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart']);
unset($_SESSION['coupons']);
```

Comment: Did you check with firebug or something like that? Is ajax request has been made? Is realex_empty_cart.php successfully respond?

Comment: Make sure you're echoing the "success" message in the php file

Comment: Make the 2nd ajax call also a post and add `data: {}`

Comment: Agreed with arunes, make sure your second ajax request is even running. do console.log(data) after your first success to make sure your second if statement `(data[0] == '00')` will even be true.

Comment: print_r($_SESSION) in realex_empty_cart.php. What is the return? Do you have session in that page?

Answer (score 0):

I think Archer has a good solution in his comment, but the reason is probably to do with caching. By default, jQuery.ajax will allow the browser to cache the response for GET requests. This means that it will not communicate with the server. Add

```
cache: false
```

to the options in your code to force it to go to the server.

```
success: function(data){                        
    // Hide payment indicator.
    jQuery('.realex_payindicator').hide();
        data = data.split("|");
        if (data[0] == '00'){                                                                                                                                           
        // Empty the shopping cart.
            jQuery.ajax({
                async: false,                                                                       
                cache: false,   
                url: templateuri+'/realex_empty_cart.php'                                                               
            });
            self.location = thankyoupage+'?order='+orderid+'&key='+orderkey;                                                                                            
        }else{
            alert(data);                            
        }                       
    }
```

(See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more info)

Owen